# uiautomatorviewer.bat file in android sdk

Tags: android

I am trying to find `uiautomatorviewer.bat` in android SDK folder.But I couldn't see anywhere in SDK folder.Could anybody tell me where is exactly `uiautomatorviewer.bat` file in android SDK?

Comment: It's in the Android_SDK\tools\bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Path_to_Android_SDK\tools\bin directory.

Comment: Sometime uiautomatorviewer.bat available in tools directory.

Comment: Yeah, it depends upon the SDK version.